# Angular 2 material tab active color customize

Tags: customization, angular-material2

I was looking to customize the active color for md-tab.
[image]

The classes in chrome dev console shows ==> -mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active. But none has any border bottom. There was a chevron class which i tried to change, but no effect.

I tried /deep/ with almost all classes.  Dint work. 
Also checked md-tab-header, but nowhere am seeing even that color! Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Found it!     use this class.

.mat-ink-bar{
  background-color:#fff;
}

Comment: If you found a solution, you can answer and accept your own solution to mark it as solved

Comment: i cannot accept my own answer for 18 hrs, is what i got as a notification.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/76110331/14557085 worked for me in angular 15.

Answer (score 12):

Try to it's work for me

```
::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color:#ee2925 !important;}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's worked for me in Angular 6

```html
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: #1f29a2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Works in Angular 7

```css
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar,.mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: #2C702A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the active underline, modify this class

```
mat-ink-bar{ background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component, set [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) to None and add the styles in your component.css file.

**Changes in Typescript code:**

import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  ....
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**Component CSS:**

```
    /* Styles for tab labels */
.mat-tab-label {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Styles for the active tab label */
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Styles for the ink bar */
.mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
  background: black;
}
```

This works with Angular 10.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is tested and works fine in Angular 10 -

```css
.tabs .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color: #5e70db;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.tabs .mat-ink-bar {
  background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

any of those solutions didn't work for me but i did a general solution without use the encapsulation.none

```
    /* Styles for tab labels */
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Styles for the active tab label */
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Styles for the ink bar */
::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: green;
}
```

using ::ng-deep you are telling to css inside material being overrite, then you can customice it