# How to change the inkbar color of the active tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is it possible to change the inkbar color of the active tab?

By default the ink bar is blue. See [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) for an example.

I tried this in SCSS, but it doesn't work.

```css
.mat-tab-label-container{
  .mat-tab-list{
    .mat-ink-bar {
      background-color: green
    }
  }
}

.mat-tab-label-active{
 color: green 
}
```

Anyone can please help,

Comment: Can't you use the `color` input?

Comment: How on earth is that CSS when there's nested CSS rules??

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: Didn't get what? I meant `<mat-tab-group color="accent">`

Comment: @Edric nested rules are allowed in SCSS...

Comment: @LucaDeNardi If you've checked the revision history of this question, you would see that the OP originally stated that the code was CSS. I was the one who modified it to be "SCSS".

Comment: @Edric I missed it then! :)

Answer (score 29):

### [image]This could be similar to what you want to achieve

Please see this link ( [Cannot style mat-tab without ::ng-deep and !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689878/cannot-style-mat-tab-without-ng-deep-and-important/48690148#48690148) ) and upvote if it helps you, I think this is similar to what you want to achieve.

### To answer your question

You need to use **Selector specificity** and then put your style in the root style /src/styles.css (NOTE: that don't put it in the components styleUrls your style will not work)

to style the ink bar

```
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
```

### Change ink-bar from underline to elliptical covering the item

You can try this code to make it elliptical to cover the item.

```
/* label style */
.mat-tab-label{
  background: #e7e7e7;
  color:  black;
  min-width: 60px!important;
}
/* focus style */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus{
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
/* ink bar style */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
   background: rgba(149, 165, 166,0.3);
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Please see the live sample here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dmgrave-ng-so-anser-tabs-style?file=styles.css

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I change ink-bar from underline to elliptical covering the item?

Comment: @Aditya I have editted my answer, please see the sample code above and live sample if that is what you want to achieve. Hope it helps.

Comment: look at image attached.,I need the same.

Comment: @Aditya I have seen the image, please see my updated live code and answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, works for me!

Comment: @Mark Glad it worked. Please mark my answer as the solution if it works on your end.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Below Lines worked for me. It is recommended to use ::ng-deep. It will be applied to child components:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: rgb(39, 184, 176) !important;
}
```

Comment: This technique is now deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

use ::ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar {
    background-color: #00d440;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Material >= 15 use this:

```
.mat-mdc-tab:not(.mat-mdc-tab-disabled) .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline, .mat-mdc-tab-link:not(.mat-mdc-tab-disabled) .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
  border-color: #0A94D0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without SCSS, you can add color to the `mat-tab-group` and it will change the color of the .mat-ink-bar:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" color="accent">
```

It will take the corresponding color of your theme then.