# How to find which css selectors I need to style any Angular material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770809/18198833)
There is several ways to style Angular materials, but the `::ng-deep` is not recommended anymore.

So the solutions seem to be custom themes, global styles with selectors to apply the style to Angular material, and also ViewEncapsulation.
From what I understand, both of them will affect other Angular material components.

Is there any way I could apply styles only to a specific material component without affecting them globally?

**More importantly**, How would I know which selectors to use?
In this case, [mat-tab case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48746742/18198833)
The answer provided a selector to target the active tab underline specifically by

`.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{}`

`.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:not(.mat-tab-disabled):focus{}`

It works great, but how could I learn to find this kind of selector myself? I would always go to Angular material documentation and try to find any input or methods that match my styling needs. But I have really no idea if this method not working what else could I do other than googling and searching on StackOverflow.

Or at this point, should I just stop trying and try to recreate a similar component by myself? Usually this way is faster, because I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: If you're familiar with [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and you're sure that's not the issue, then provide a concrete example code - a concrete element you want to style and its context. And also describe exactly how you want to style it.